# CUB template similar to thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, thrust, cub

Following is a thrust code:

```
h_in_value[7] = thrust::reduce(thrust::device, d_in1 + a - b, d_ori_rho_L1 + a);
```

Here, the `thrust::reduce` takes the first and last input iterator, and thrust returns the value back to the CPU(copied to h_in_value)

Can this functionality be obtained using CUB?

1. First and Last iterators as inputs
2. Returning the result back to host

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can this functionality be obtained using CUB?

Yes, its possible to do something similar using CUB.  Most of what you need is contained [here](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_reduce.html#ab7f21e8255eb842aaf74305975ae607f) in the example snippet for sum reduce.  In addition, CUB does not automatically copy quantities back to host code, so we need to manage that.  Here is one possible implementation:

```
$ cat t125.cu
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <cub/cub.cuh>
#include <iostream>

typedef int mytype;

const int dsize = 10;
const int val  = 1;


template <typename T>
T my_cub_reduce(T *begin, T *end){

  size_t num_items = end-begin;
  T *d_in = begin;
  T *d_out, res;
  cudaMalloc(&d_out, sizeof(T));
  void     *d_temp_storage = NULL;
  size_t   temp_storage_bytes = 0;
  cub::DeviceReduce::Sum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, d_in, d_out, num_items);
  // Allocate temporary storage
  cudaMalloc(&d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes);
  // Run sum-reduction
  cub::DeviceReduce::Sum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, d_in, d_out, num_items);
  cudaMemcpy(&res, d_out, sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaFree(d_out);
  cudaFree(d_temp_storage);
  return res;
}

template <typename T>
typename thrust::iterator_traits<T>::value_type
my_cub_reduce(T begin, T end){

  return my_cub_reduce(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&(begin[0])), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&(end[0])));
}

int main(){

  mytype *d_data, *h_data;
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, dsize*sizeof(mytype));
  h_data = (mytype *)malloc(dsize*sizeof(mytype));
  for (int i = 0; i < dsize; i++) h_data[i] = val;
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, dsize*sizeof(mytype), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  std::cout << "thrust reduce: " << thrust::reduce(thrust::device, d_data, d_data+dsize) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "cub reduce:    " << my_cub_reduce(d_data, d_data+dsize) << std::endl;
  thrust::device_vector<int> d(5,1);
  // using thrust style container iterators and pointers
  std::cout << my_cub_reduce(d.begin(), d.end()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << my_cub_reduce(thrust::device_pointer_cast(d.data()), thrust::device_pointer_cast(d.data()+d.size())) << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t125 t125.cu
$ ./t125
thrust reduce: 10
cub reduce:    10
5
5
$
```

EDIT: with a few extra lines of code, we can add support for thrust-style device container iterators and pointers.  I've updated the code above to demonstrate that as well.

Comment: I want to replace the thrust library with Cub in a algorithm I wanted to parallelize and optimize(Cub is supposed to be faster in implementation). But the above CUB implementation is proving to be slower than thrust when I analyzed it on nvvp. The cudamalloc d_temp_storage and cudafree d_temp_storage seem to be the reason for this. Any idea how this could be fixed ? Also can you mention the significance of two cub operations ? @Robert Crovella

Comment: CUB is probably faster than thrust in some cases.  However for a basic reduction there might not be much difference.  In fact thrust uses CUB for some operations.  In your question, you basically said you wanted to duplicate thrust functionality, but CUB is a lot more flexible than thrust.  So if you were going to use this operation more than once, you would probably allocate the temp storage once, and then re-use it from call to call.  In that scenario, cub might be quicker than thrust.  You could also reuse the allocation for the return value.